# Python regex - address parsing

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x, pattern-matching

I'm trying to parse two types of one-line address strings:

```
Flat XXX, XXX <Building name>, <City/town>, <State> <Postcode>

DDD <Generic place name>, <Road name> road, <City/town>, <State>
```

using using the following regex

```
re.search(r'(Flat \w+)?\W*(.+)\W*([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+\s+\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2})?
```

Here `XXX` is some alphanumeric string, and `DDD` is a number. I expect group 1 to be `Flat XXX` if the address is of the first type or `None` if not, group 2 to be `XXX <Building name>, <City/town>, <State>` if the address if of the first type, or `<Road name> road, <City/town>, <State>` if it is of the second type, and group 3 to be the postcode if the address is of the first type or `None` if not. The postcode is a UK postcode for which my regex (not comprehensively accurate but mostly correct for my purpose) is `[a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+\s+\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2}`. Case is to be ignored and there may be no comma between `Flat XXX` (if it exists) and `<Building name>`, and there may be a comma between the city and the postcode (if it exists).

```
>>> address1 = 'Flat 29, Victoria House, Redwood Lane, Richmond, London SW14 9XY'
>>> re.search(r'(Flat \w+)?\W*(.+)\W*([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+\s+\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2})?', address1, re.I).groups()
>>> ('Flat 29', 'Victoria House, Redwood Lane, Richmond, London SW14 9XY', None)
>>> address2 = '91 Fleet, Major Road, Fleet, Hampshire'
>>> re.search(r'(Flat \w+)?\W*(.+)\W*([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+\s+\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2})?', address2, re.I).groups()
>>> (None, '91 Fleet, Major Road, Fleet, Hampshire', None)
```

I am not sure what is going wrong, but I think the middle group `..\W*(.+)\W*..` is more or less capturing everything.

Comment: Yes, it is: https://regex101.com/r/uC6fiZ/1

Comment: What do you ultimately need to get from the addresses?

Comment: Have you considered and tried the non-greedy version: `..\W*(.+?)\W*..`?

Comment: I described what I need: I expect group 1 to be `Flat XXX` if the address is of the first type or `None` if not, group 2 to be `XXX <Building name>, <City/town>, <State>` if the address if of the first type, or `<Road name> road, <City/town>, <State>` if it is of the second type, and group 3 to be the postcode if the address is of the first type or `None` if not.

Comment: The non-greedy version gives me `('Flat 29', 'V', None)` for the first type of address, e.g. for `address1 = Flat 29, Victoria House, Redwood Lane, Richmond, London SW14 9XY`.

Comment: I don't need `\W*` before and after the middle group, actually this is to filter out any possible commas between `Flat XXX` (if it exists) and the middle group.

Comment: I've tried this regex `(Flat \w+)*,*\s*(.+),*\s*([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+\s+\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2})*`, but it gives me the same results as I posted above.

Answer (score 1):

It's not particularly elegant, but here's a bit of a workaround (assuming that `<State>` doesn't contain any digits):

```
import re
addresses = ['Flat 29, Victoria House, Redwood Lane, Richmond, London SW14 9XY',
             '91 Fleet, Major Road, Fleet, Hampshire']

regexp = re.compile(r'(Flat \w+)?[,\s]*(.*)\s([a-zA-Z]{1,2}\d+\s?+\d+[a-zA-Z]{1,2}|\D*)$', re.I)

for address in addresses:
    sep_addr = list(re.search(regexp, address).groups())
    if not any(x.isdigit() for x in sep_addr[2]):
        sep_addr[1] +=  ' ' + sep_addr[2]
        sep_addr[2] = None
    print sep_addr
```

We set group 2 to be either the postcode or the last word in the provided address. Then by checking if there are any digits in the result of our second group, we know if it's a postcode or not. If it isn't, we append to group 1 to give the full address part, and set group 2 to `None`. This returns:

```
['Flat 29', 'Victoria House, Redwood Lane, Richmond, London', 'SW14 9XY']
[None, '91 Fleet, Major Road, Fleet, Hampshire', None]
```

EDIT: added an optional to the space in the middle of the postcode, to ensure space-less postcodes are still matched.